# Flask alchemy doesn't create database table for the model class

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I created a simple boilerplate flask application with one class in the model. My problem is that my **app doesn't create the table** in the mysql database after the app first run. Ideally, table should be created only if it doesn't exist (so I can leave the `create_all` instruction in the code)

project tree is:

```
.
├── application.py
├── module
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   └── models.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
└── templates
```

That's the content of `application.py` file

```
from flask import Flask
from module import db


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://oskar:secret@ipaddress/analytics'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # with app.app_context():
    db.init_app(app)

    app.app_context().push()

    # create tables only once
    db.create_all(app=app)
    db.session.commit()

    app.run()
```

Content of `module/__init__.py`

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

Content of `module/models.py`

```
from module import db


class PostalCodeCities(db.Model):

    postal_code = db.Column(db.String(6), nullable=False)  # kod pocztowy
    city = db.Column(db.String(126), nullable=False)  # miejscowosc
    street = db.Column(db.String(126))
    building = db.Column(db.String(32))
    municipality = db.Column(db.String(126))  # gmina
    county = db.Column(db.String(126))  # powiat
    voivodeship = db.Column(db.String(126))  # wojewodztwo

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<PostalEntry %r>' % self.postal_code
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the solution. I had to move everything from `__init__.py` to `models.py` and in `applications.py` import `db` from `module.models`